# Three.js divide planeGeometry to non-equal parts by heightSegments & widthSegments

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to divide planeGeometry to non-equal parts by heightSegments & widthSegments in `three.js`?

Explain :

```
new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 2, 3);
```

thats will divide the plane to 2 equal parts in the width and 3 equal parts in the height.

I want to divide to non-equal parts. Something like :

```
new THREE.PlaneGeometry(objWidth, objHeight, 2.5, 1.5);
```

which did not work. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the [API documentation for `THREE.PlaneGeometry`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Geometries/PlaneGeometry) you can see that the 3rd and 4th argument mean `widthSegments` and `heightSegments`:

```
PlaneGeometry(width, height, widthSegments, heightSegments);
```

The amount of segments is an integer. I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but those values are supposed to be whole numbers.

So no, this is not possible.

Comment: what im trying to achieve is distribution of plane geometry to non equal parts.